# Spanning columns with TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of “colspan” in an Android TableLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710793/what-is-the-equivalent-of-colspan-in-an-android-tablelayout)

It says in the documentation for TableLayout "Cells can span columns, as they can in HTML." However, I can't find any way to do so.

Specifically, I have one row with two columns and another with one column. I want the one column row to span the entire table. Seems easy, but I don't see it.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2710793/165674

Answer (score 80, accepted):

add android:layout_span="3" to span 3 columns.
For example:

```
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:id="@+id/item_id"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="item text" />     
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Ahh, there it is, in TableRow.LayoutParams: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Finding those layout XML files is tricky -- easy to forget the android:layout_* attributes are in separate javadocs.

Comment: -1, This solution does not work when the text of the button is too small. For example when the text is only a `+` like in a calculator app, the button will not grow until it covers two columns (if those two columns are wider than the button is without the columnSpan).

Comment: Why we can't use weight on above view i.e button

Answer (score 3):

android:layout_span does the trick.

example:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="some text"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="some other text" 
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView android:text="more text" 
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```