# How can I set tablerow of differnt width in Tablelayout?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

[My expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUHNk.jpg)

This is referenced Image of what I want,
But im unable to do it, currently im using tablelayout, what i should do?
Ofcourse my total requirement are vertical and horizontal scrolling.

My current code is below with this I cant even have row of diff width, same width get applied to all below rows of column

```
/* create cell element - button */
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            100,
                        100);
//                tableRowParams.column=1;
//                tableRowParams.span=2;
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item_header, tableRow, false);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
                TextView tv_label = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_label);
                LinearLayout ll_row = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll_row);
                tv_label.setText("dynamic " + i);
                ll_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6ab04c"));
//                ll_row.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
//                ll_row.getLayoutParams().width = 400;
//                ll_row.requestLayout();
                tableRow.addView(v);
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            } else {
                TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//                tableRowParams.column=1;
//                tableRowParams.span=1;

                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item_header, tableRow, false);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
                TextView tv_label = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_label);
                LinearLayout ll_row = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll_row);
                tv_label.setText("dynamic " + i);
                ll_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6ab04c"));
//                ll_row.getLayoutParams().height = 300;
//                ll_row.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
//                ll_row.requestLayout();
                tableRow.addView(v);
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            }


        }
```

My current Output is this:
[My Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8LKm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you cannot control the widths of individual cells on a row, the core concept of the TableView layout is that **ALL** cells in a column have the same width, thus you cannot individually adjust the width of a cell on a row.

**BUT** you can specify that a cell can span multiple columns with [android:layout_span](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_span) and this should get you what you want to do.

e.g. on Row 2 in your picture you would set the cell in the "12" column to span two columns (i.e. "12" and "13")

As an example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12724322/2373819) gives more details

Comment: I tried span but didnt get expected output , you can see            tableRowParams.column=1;
//                tableRowParams.span=2;  this comment i have added this didnt worked

Comment: But you set the params on the tablerow itself `tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);` whereas you need to this parameter on the thing instead the cell you want to be spanned e.g. `v.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams)` as per the answer linked

Comment: oh okay gotcha!